# Is it possible to place a button as layout_above="view1 && view2"?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Is it possible to place a, for example, button as layout_above="two different views"

The reason I wonder this is because I have two different views that slides up in the UI. If I can't put the button as layout_above for both of those view, one view will cover the button.

Any suggestion on this?

I tried with doing it programmatically but I couldn't get it to work. Neither did I find any thread on this, so I hope somebody here has knowledge about this. :)

Just a test code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bu_myButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/view1"    // This is where I wanna add two views! Like "@id/view1 || @id/view2"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_myButton"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

NOTE: One of those view will have View.Visibility=GONE, when the other is visible, and somethimes both will have View.Visibilty=GONE.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make your layout like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bu_myButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="1"
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="2"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="3"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here your Button bu_myButton will be always above button1 & button2. Following your note, I am making 3 cases here -

1. bu_myButton is always visible, button2 is visible(use android:visibility="visible"), button3 is invisible(use android:visibility="gone")
2. bu_myButton is always visible, button2 is invisible(use android:visibility="gone"), button3 is visible(use android:visibility="visible")
3. bu_myButton is always visible, button2 is visible(use android:visibility="visible"), button3 is visible(use android:visibility="visible")

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

If you have any input on this solution, please let me know! This did the work, and will be the solution, until I find out a greater one!

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bu_myButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewParent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_mylocation"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, the viewParent controls how the button should appear. If visible, button will move up, if not, button will move to the usual position.

Also, I set the view1 and view2 visible depending on which button is fired. So it's both viewParent.VISIBLE and view1.VISIBLE(or view2), not a beautiful solution, but it does the job.